# Flyway - Data migrations on multiple databases - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

Let's say there's a `service` (spring boot service) with two dependencies `d1` and `d2`.

`d1` and `d2` are modules, each of which speaks to a different database `db1` and `db2` respectively.

When I run the service, I want the `sql` files in each of the modules (`d1` and `d2`) to be ingested into their respective databases (`db1` and `db2`).

**What I tried:**

I tried by placing the Flyway configuration `flyway.url` in each of the modules with the `url` as the respective database connection URL.

And the `sql` files in each of the modules are named as `VX__NAME.sql` (X=1,2,3..)

When I ran the service with the command `mvn spring-boot:run` I get an error saying that `sql` files with same versions found. I presume it's because the two modules fall under the same parent service.

[image]

I've gone through similar questions - dealing Flyway with multiple databases but none of the answers helped me.

Comment: Do you have flyway dependency in your parent? Maybe if you would have flyway dependency in each module and not in you parent it would somehow work. Can you try it?

Comment: I've just now checked the same and I get the same error "Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found more than one migration with version 1"

Answer (score 0):

I am also researching the topic of using Flyway or Liquibase in my spring boot app.  So, I have no experience but I have read about using `{vendor}` placeholder and about needed structure for migrations (`/resources/db/migrations/{vendor}`).

Maybe that helps?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html